# How can I call "glEnable" using Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to make the world's simplest test of an android environment, just to get all my ducks in a row before tackling the port.

The very FIRST thing I need to do is just link GLES 1.0 ... here's the steps I took:

ONE: Using Android Studio 2.3.2, I created a new C++ enabled project with a basic activity

TWO: in AndroidManifest.xml I added this:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010000" />
```

THREE: In CMakeLists.txt I added these lines:

```
find_package( ZLIB REQUIRED )
find_library( GLES1_LIBRARY names GLESv1_CM )
include_directories( ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLES_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
...
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   native-lib
                   ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}
                   ${GLES1_LIBRARIES}
                   ${log-lib} )
```

That works for log-lib, and it works for zlib too... it doesn't work for GLES1 (see next step)

FOUR: I just added one simple line to native-lib.cpp

```
 glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

Hit compile and...

```
CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o: In function `Java_com_game_raptisoft_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI':
C:\Users\Raptisoft2011\Desktop\Android\MyApplication\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:12: undefined reference to `glEnable'
```

How do I resolve this problem?  Are there more link statements I need to include?  I've tried various iterations of GLES1_LIBRARY (like GLES_LIBRARY, etc) but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
               native-lib
               ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}
               EGL
               GLESv1_CM
               ${log-lib} )
```

Also, you have targeted `${GLES1_LIBRARIES}`, but above you've spelled it `GLES1_LIBRARY`

---

If you can, I would suggest porting to gles2.  The most you would have to worry about is writing shaders, and it gives you better control over how your data is drawn.

---

BTW, is this the same Rapitsoft that created Chuzzle using the PopCap framework?

Comment: It is... but Chuzzle isn't in the Popcap framework, I rolled my own.  My framework is cross platform-- except for Android.  Trying to rectify that now, but boy, it's fighting me every step of the way.

Comment: BTW, the solution you gave me works-- as long as I leave EGL out.  At least, it works to compile.  Sadly it crashes on startup now.  So... as always, a new mountain to climb. :)

Comment: I'd say to start with this example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-activity  and start adding code to it to draw.  After working with a successful android app, then start working on porting.

Comment: I sent an email to your tech support line, I hope you don't mind.